# Docker Error response from daemon: Cannot start container

Tags: docker, centos6

I need help. I have a problem with docker. My OS is Centos 6. tnx

$ sudo docker run -it --name atom-mysql -p 3310:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -d mysql/mysql-server:5.5.44

Unable to find image 'mysql/mysql-server:5.5.44' locally 5.5.44: Pulling from mysql/mysql-server

8c3e49cb06dc: Pull complete 90fed8b1ceab: Pull complete 8a2b759d9dd8: Pull complete 33529391d37f: Pull complete 4268ebc0501a: Pull complete 71c6842c97e5: Pull complete 80c90f40a6e5: Pull complete 0be01ae3bd72: Pull complete b1b23a5825ac: Pull complete d4b9b32ae2f0: Already exists Digest: sha256:64c6209e62002209ea3f35125bf6e10f9f4807a3a80bc1f3730c8b8313dad457 Status: Downloaded newer image for mysql/mysql-server:5.5.44 264a844c0f2b6e7f6a9fff872d401709216fb5704d24225233972f0719e52b6c

Error response from daemon: Cannot start container 264a844c0f2b6e7f6a9fff872d401709216fb5704d24225233972f0719e52b6c: iptables failed: iptables -t filter -A DOCKER ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp -d 172.17.0.4 --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name. (exit status 1)

Comment: CentOS 6 is out of support, only runs very old versions of Docker, and then just barely.  I’d suggest upgrading to a newer host OS if you need to use Docker.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you missing docker firewall rules. Docker creates own iptables chains named DOCKER*. You can see it by the command `iptables -L`

```
...
Chain DOCKER (4 references)
...
Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
...
Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (4 references)
...
Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
...
```

If you don't see at least DOCKER chain you need to find why do you miss that.
Try to restart docker service to reinit docker iptables rules:

`service docker restart`

But keep in mind that **this action will stop all running containers**.

Comment: tnx epic friend!